# For which natural n is $3^n+5^n$ divisible by $3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For which natural n is $3^n+5^n$ divisible by $3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}$? I only got that $3^n+5^n=8k$ when $n$ is odd. How to solve this one?

Comment: $n=1$ is a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$3(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})=3^n+3*5^{n-1}<3^n+5^n<5*3^{n-1}+5^n=5(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$$
So the ratio is between $3$ and $5$, so it equals $4$.
$$4*3^{n-1}+4*5^{n-1}=3^n+5^n=3*3^{n-1}+5*5^{n-1}\\3^{n-1}=5^{n-1}$$

Comment: cool. but what if the ratio is not integer?

Comment: Essentially, $n$ can only be one.

Comment: @Jackie: If $3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}$ divides $3^n+5^n$, then by definition, $\dfrac{3^n+5^n}{3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}}$ is an integer.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oh yeah I see how could I not notice that

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n=5^n+3^n,$

If $d$ divides $A_m,A_{m-1}$

$d$ will divide  $A_m-3A_{m-1}=2\cdot5^{m-1}$

$d$ will divide  $5A_{m-1}-A_m=2\cdot3^{m-1}$

So, $d$ will divide  $(2\cdot3^{m-1},2\cdot5^{m-1})=2(3,5)^{m-1}=2$

So, the necessary condition for $A_{m-1}\mid A_m$ is $: A_{m-1}$ must divide $2$