# Find all possible positive integers $n$ such that $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1} \mid 3^n + 5^n $. Proof explanation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, proof-explanation

**Question:** Find all possible positive integers $n$ such that $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1} \mid 3^n + 5^n $.

**Solution:**  Let's suppose that $3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}\mid 3^n+5^n$, so there is some positive integer $k$ such that $3^n+5^n=k(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$. Now, if $k\ge 5$ we have $$k(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})\ge 5(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})=5\cdot 3^{n-1}+5\cdot 5^{n-1}>3^n+5^n.$$

This means that $k\le 4$. On the other hand, $3^n+5^n=3\cdot 3^{n-1}+5\cdot 5^{n-1}>3(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$, then $k\ge 4$ and thus we deduce that $k=4$. In this case we have $3^n+5^n=4(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$, which gives us the equation $5^{n-1}=3^{n-1}$, but if $n>1$ this equation is impossible.

Hence $n=1$

The above solution is from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2109553/242). Could someone please explain a few things:

- why was the value of $k\le4$ and $k\ge4$ picked? where did they get 4?
- why does $3\cdot 3^{n-1}+5\cdot 5^{n-1}>3(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$ mean that $k\ge4$ ?
- Why does $5\cdot 3^{n-1}+5\cdot 5^{n-1}>3^n+5^n.$ mean that $k\le4$ ?

Comment: Which other math stack exchange solution?

Comment: It's kinda misleading they should've picked $k\geq5$ proved it doesn't hold then take $k\leq 3$ prove it doesn't hold then take $k=4$ as the only possible solution.

Comment: If no $k\geq 5$ is a solution and if no $k\leq 3$ is a solution then the only possible choice left is $k=4$

Comment: @lhf Related to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955040/for-which-natural-n-is-3n5n-divisible-by-3n-15n-1

Comment: The [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2109553/133781) you wrote is mine. The idea behind my solution was basically to bound $k$. This is a common trick to solve some problems of divisibility or diophantine equations.

Answer (score 1):

The line $$k(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})\ge 5(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})=5\cdot 3^{n-1}+5\cdot 5^{n-1}>3^n+5^n$$
makes a contradiction, since $k(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})=3^n+5^n$, and $3^n+5^n>3^n+5^n$ is obviously false. Since they assumed $k\geq 5$, that must be false; thus, we conclude $k\leq 4$.

---

Then they say $$3^n+5^n>3(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$$ which you could rewrite to
$$3^n+5^n=k(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}>3(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$$
thus $k>3$, and since $k\leq 4$, we know $k=4$.

---

They're basically just first eliminating all numbers greater than four, and then all integers smaller than four, to conclude $k=4$ (which they eliminate too).

Comment: That problem is reducable to this one since $3\cdot 4=12$ and $5\cdot 4=20$. And they simply choose those numbers because it works in this case. Often in mathematics, methods are seemingly arbitrary but chosen because they work.

Comment: No, $12^{n-1}+20^{n-1}\mid 12^n+20^n$ reduces to $4^{n-1}(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})\mid 4^n(3^n+5^n)$, which can be written as $3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}\mid 4(3^n+5^n)$. See how you can apply above method to solve this?

Comment: Please avoid changing your question to something else, ask a new question to make it easier for people to find their specific question in the future.

Comment: I just tried that, and it seems like we'd need another approach in case of $12$ and $20$. I made a mistake in my earlier reasoning, so you can consider my above comments regarding the $12,20$ case useless.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier way to look at it: the equation
$$3^n+5^n=k(3^{n-1}+5^{n-1})$$
can be rewritten
$$5^{n-1}(5-k)=3^{n-1}(k-3)\ .$$
Therefore $5-k$ and $k-3$ must have the same sign.  They can't both be negative as then $k$ would be simultaneously less than $3$ and greater than $5$, and they clearly can't both be zero, so they must both be positive.  Hence
$$k<5\quad\hbox{and}\quad k>3\ ,$$
so $k=4$.  This makes our second equation
$$5^{n-1}=3^{n-1}\ ,$$
and this is true if and only if $n-1=0$.

Comment: I don't know, did you try it?

Comment: I don't think it's either, please post your working.